# Gather several tasks to one task in gradle

Tags: gradle

I use several tasks in my gradle project like this:

```
gradle clean build jacocoTestReport jacocoIntegrationTestReport sonar
```

How can I "merge" this task (with orders) into one task "doFancyStuff" ?

Comment: What did you already tried to do to combine all tasks? Edit your question to include that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it via setting depends of your custom task and setting each task's mustRunAfter parameter. Something like this:

```
task doFancyStuff(dependsOn: ['clean', 'build', 'jacocoTestReport', 'jacocoIntegrationTestReport', 'sonar'])
build.mustRunAfter clean
jacocoTestReport.mustRunAfter build
jacocoIntegrationTestReport.mustRunAfter jacocoTestReport
sonar.mustRunAfter jacocoIntegrationTestReport
```